# Add Total column to Dynamic SQL pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, sql-server-2016, subtotal

Lots of these types of questions out there, but unable to find anything that matches what I am looking for.

I am using code from another post that is working great, but I would like to modify it to add a totals row at the bottom of the table.

The previous post so the creator gets credit is: [SQL Server dynamic pivot with multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39371327/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-with-multiple-columns)

My current table looks like:

| Work_Group | Avg | 01/01/2021 | 01/01/2021 | 01/01/2021 | ect... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Blue | 5 | 2 | 5 | 8 |  |
| Green | 5 | 2 | 5 | 8 |  |

Goal:

| Work_Group | Avg | 01/01/2021 | 01/01/2021 | 01/01/2021 | ect... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Blue | 5 | 2 | 5 | 8 |  |
| Green | 5 | 2 | 5 | 8 |  |
| TOTAL | 10 | 4 | 10 | 16 |  |

Current Code is:

```
DECLARE @colsEAST AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @pivotCountEAST AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @sqlEAST AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @colsEAST = ISNULL(@colsEAST + ', ', '') + QUOTENAME(Load_Date)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Load_Date FROM ##CE_tmpEast_ALL) AS Load_Date

SET @pivotCountEAST = N'SELECT Work_Group, ' + @colsEAST +'
FROM (SELECT Work_Group, Load_Date, Count FROM ##CEtmp_East_ALL) AS Count
PIVOT(SUM(Count) FOR Load_Date IN (' + @colsEAST + ')) AS pvt';

SET @sqlEAST = '; WITH MTD_CountPivot AS (
'+@pivotCountEAST+'
),

MTD_Pivot_Tables AS (
  SELECT Work_Group, AVG(Count) AS [AVG Count]
  FROM ##CEtmp_East_ALL
  GROUP BY Work_Group
)
SELECT MTD_CountPivot.Work_Group,  MTD_Pivot_Tables.[AVG Count], ' + @colsEAST + '
FROM
MTD_CountPivot

INNER JOIN MTD_Pivot_Tables ON MTD_CountPivot.Work_Group = MTD_Pivot_Tables.Work_Group';

EXEC sp_executesql @sqlEAST;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Thank you

Comment: add a union all to input table? with group by(on a dummy column) + sum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `GROUPING SETS ((mcp.Work_Group),())` to the current query in order to get subtotals. For this, need to create another parameter `@colsEAST2` in order to hold generated list of the dates for column headers as

`SUM([2001-01-01]) AS [2001-01-01],SUM([2001-01-02]) AS [2001-01-02],SUM([2001-01-03]) AS [2001-01-03]`

along with `@colsEAST` which holds

`[2001-01-01],[2001-01-02],[2001-01-03]`

```
DECLARE @colsEAST       AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @colsEAST2      AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @pivotCountEAST AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @sqlEAST        AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @colsEAST = ISNULL(@colsEAST + ', ', '') + QUOTENAME(Load_Date)
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Load_Date 
          FROM ##CE_tmpEast_ALL) AS Load_Date;    
SELECT @colsEAST2 = ISNULL(@colsEAST2 + ', ', '') 
                + ' SUM('+QUOTENAME(Load_Date)+') AS '+QUOTENAME(Load_Date)
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Load_Date 
          FROM ##CE_tmpEast_ALL) AS Load_Date;    
SET @pivotCountEAST = N'SELECT Work_Group, ' + @colsEAST2 +'
                          FROM (SELECT Work_Group, Load_Date, Count 
                                  FROM ##CE_tmpEast_ALL) AS Count
                         PIVOT(SUM(Count) FOR Load_Date IN (' + @colsEAST + ')) AS pvt
                         GROUP BY Work_Group';                             
SET @sqlEAST = '; WITH MTD_CountPivot AS (
'+@pivotCountEAST+'
), MTD_Pivot_Tables AS (
  SELECT Work_Group, AVG(Count) AS [AVG Count]
    FROM ##CE_tmpEast_ALL
   GROUP BY Work_Group
)
SELECT CASE WHEN GROUPING(mcp.Work_Group) = 0 
            THEN mcp.Work_Group 
            ELSE ''TOTAL'' 
             END AS Work_Group,
       SUM(mpt.[AVG Count]) AS Avg, 
       ' + @colsEAST2+ '
  FROM MTD_CountPivot mcp
  JOIN MTD_Pivot_Tables mpt 
    ON mcp.Work_Group = mpt.Work_Group
 GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((mcp.Work_Group),())';    
EXEC sp_executesql @sqlEAST;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=4557b5e665b392fb48980cd50a73aac3)</kbd>